# Change row color of listview with boolean

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have these codes :

```
    public Boolean extension(string namearq)
    {
        Boolean sirve; string exte;
        exte = Path.GetExtension(namearq);
        if (exte == ".xml") { sirve = true; }
        else { sirve = false; }
        return sirve;

    }
```

this code above is for detect the kind of fila , and the code below is for populate the listview with the files of any folder,

```
     txtActivo.Text = folder.SelectedPath;
            local = txtActivo.Text + "\\";
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            string[] listaaraq = Directory.GetFiles(local);
            foreach ( string eleman in listaaraq )
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(eleman.Substring(eleman.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
                color = vercon1.extension(eleman.Substring(eleman.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
            }
```

I want to change the background color of the rows when color is false.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Extension Methods in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx) need to be in a `static` class and a `static` method where the first argument will be the extension followed by the `this` keyword, for sample:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Extension(this object obj, string namearq)
    {
        Boolean sirve; string exte;

        exte = Path.GetExtension(namearq);
        return (exte == ".xml");
    }
}
```

And you can call using

```
obj.Extension(string);
```

the `obj` object will be passed to extension method on the first argument automatically.

*PS: I'm not sure about your code, change the type you want to extend and apply.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        var item = new ListViewItem(eleman.Substring(eleman.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
        color = vercon1.extension(eleman.Substring(eleman.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
        if (!color)
        {
            item.BackColor = Color.Red; //choose your color
        }

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
```